# need get all key from object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have data in following format

```
[
  { _id: ObjectId, spec: { abc: 'abc', bcd: 'bcd', cde: 'cde' } },
  { _id: ObjectId, spec: { bcd: 'bcd', cde: 'cde', efg: 'efg' } },
  { _id: ObjectId, spec: { cde: 'cde', efg: 'efg', ghi: 'ghi' } },
  { _id: ObjectId, spec: { ghi: 'ghi', abc: 'abc', bcd: 'bcd' } }
];
```

I need to get all keys from the `spec` object from all objects using aggregation like this.

```
['abc','bcd','cde','efg','ghi']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `$objectToArray` convert `spec` object to array in key-value format
- `$unwind` deconstruct `spec` array
- `$group` by null and construct the unique array of `spec` object's key using `$addToSet`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { spec: { $objectToArray: "$spec" } } },
  { $unwind: "$spec" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      spec: { $addToSet: "$spec.k" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XpnakhqRgG-)